# Dictionary values starting with zero

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to build a dictionary for my contact's names and their phone number:

```
contacts = {'name': 0500456}
```

but it shows error:

> contacts = {'name': 0500456} SyntaxError: invalid token

Python3 think I want to write octal number, so the suggested solution was:

```
contacts = {'name': 0o500456}
```

But that's not what I need!
I want to write integer numbers that start with zero as dictionary value.

Is there a solution! or should I put them inside a string quotes?

Comment: it has to be a string.

Comment: @Resistory When I have an integer starting with 0, it says `SyntaxError: invalid token`

Answer (score 3):

You need to choose between storing an integer object and storing a string object.

Choose an **integer object** (`500456`) if you need to perform calculations using the value of the integer. This will not store any leading zero information, but if you just need a fixed number of zeroes at some point in front of the integer, you can always do a `'0' + str()` when you need it in that form.

If you're not actually using the integer value in your program and just need to spit the value back out later with leading zeroes, then go ahead and convert it to a **string object** (`'0500456'`) immediately as you mentioned.

If you need to use the value of the integer but the number of leading zeroes is significant, then either store it as a string and convert to `int()` when needed, or create a custom class, perhaps an integer subclass that stores the leading zero information and includes it when `__str__()` is called.